# How to Determine If a VirtualBox Appliance Is Headless?

Tags: bash, virtual-machine, virtualbox

A VirtualBox virtual machine may be launched headless or with the traditional GUI type. I've sifted through the `vboxmanage` documentation but can't find a way query the current type. Short of grepping running processes or X windows, what's the best mechanism to determine if a VM is headless from Bash?

Note: I also tried diffing `vboxmanage showvminfo` and `vboxmanage guestproperty enumerate` between headless and GUI sessions but the only deltas were timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas...

If you're using Linux try comparing their /proc/${PID} directories. Maybe you could find the open socket in fd/ or a DISPLAY env set in environ. Beware it's zero-terminated (use tr '\0' '\n').

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I'm really looking for a more builtin and supported mechanism (i.e., I want to avoid avoid grepping processes).